# pgfplots in beamer class with BaKoMa TeX

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, bakoma

I have a problem concerning plotting of functions in `beamer` class with `pgfplots`. I use BaKoMa TeX. In the article class, all works fine, but switching to beamer, an error occurs as soon as `\usepackage{pgfplots}` is implemented:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=427790].
\pgfkeys@non@outer@newif@ ...ame #2true\endcsname
{\noexpand \let \noexpand ...
l.3343 }
```

The minimum example I work with is the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ xlabel=Cost, ylabel=Error]
\addplot[color=red,mark=x]
coordinates {
(2,-2.8559703)
(3,-3.5301677)
(4,-4.3050655)
(5,-5.1413136)
(6,-6.0322865)
(7,-6.9675052)
(8,-7.9377747) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you use \begin{frame} ... \end{frame}?

Comment: Yes, a friend used another compiler instead of BaKoMa where no problem occurs.

Comment: @Malte could you write `\tracingmacros=2 \tracingcommands=2` right after `\begin{tikzpicture}`, compile, abort on the first error, and then send the resulting `.log` file to me by mail (perhaps as zip file)? My mail address can be found in the `pgfplots` manual.

Answer (score 2):

Just extend pool_size value in TEXMF.INI file.

More details may be found in Support section of BaKoMa TeX site.

Comment: You should provide the details here as well, Basil, so the answer could be self-contained. Also include a link to the "Support section".